# ef core seperate migration project

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I followed the instruction from **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli** and created two seperate migration project one for MsSQL and the other one is for PostgreSQL

I have three project

1- Persistence project that has include all repositories and ApplicationDatabaseContext definitions

2- MsSQL migration project

3- PostgreSQL migration project

If I set startup project to 1 and default project to 3 at **Package Manager Console** and run the **update-database** command, migration from seperate folder was successfuly applied to database.

But If I use **await _context.Database.MigrateAsync(cancellationToken)** code from one of resository I am getting below error

> Message : The given assembly name was invalid. # Source :
> System.Private.CoreLib # Stack Trace :

Here is my **DbContextOptionBuilder** method

**PostgreSqlMigrationsAssembly => "PostgreSQLMigrations.dll"**

```
var assemblyWorkingLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var assemblyFile = Path.Combine(assemblyWorkingLocation, PostgreSqlMigrationsAssembly);

    string workingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(workingDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile(SettingJsonFile)
        .Build();

    var provider = configuration[ProviderType];
    var connectionString = configuration[ConnectionString];

    if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        return;
    switch (provider)
    {
        case null:
            throw new UnSupportedDatabaseException("Unsupported database provider.Please check appSettings.json.");
        case "mssql":
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, serverOptions => serverOptions.MigrationsAssembly(MsSqlMigrationsAssembly));
            break;
        case "postgresql":
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connectionString, serverOptions => serverOptions.MigrationsAssembly(assemblyFile));
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnSupportedDatabaseException("Unsupported database provider.Please check appSettings.json.");
    }
```

Need some help please